# Caterpillar identification: tan with black triangles

Tags: identification, insects

What will this become?  Found just north of Washington, D.C., tan with black triangles, about 1.5 inches.  The fibres around its head are not part of it.

[image: Caterpillar in DC]

[image: Caterpillar in DC]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like one of the armyworm caterpillars, probably one called Yellow Striped Armyworm, link below for image, although there are other images on line that are much more brightly coloured, showing distinct yellow and black coloration. They do vary a bit in appearance according to maturity and time of year, but either way, its an armyworm, and they turn into moths, and its probably not something you want in your garden if there are lots of them

http://bugguide.net/node/view/473723

And information about armyworms generally here, with control methods if its necessary

http://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/garden-pests/armyworm-control/